# interfaces in multiple inheritance in java, modelling issue

Tags: java, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have the following scenario:

[image]

As you can see, I have two classes that are Lecturers and Students. The class Teacher Assistants are a mix between Lectures and Students, that is because they can enrolled into courses, but they can also lecture some basic topics (without being considered Lecturers). I came with the idea to model this situation using Interfaces because I will program in in Java. Is this modelling correct?

[image]

So that the TA class will implement the Interface Teaches, which contains an array of the courses assigned to this student to teach.

But if I model in that way I realize that I am loosing the class Lecturers at all. How I can model this situation of multiple inheritance, but not loosing the class Lecturers? I mean if I program Lecturers as an interface it would not have any methods that I would need further, for example, calculus of its wage benefits and so on. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `Lecturer` into an interface, then have both `TeachingAssistant` and `Professor` implement it. `TeachingAssistant` can extend `Student`, because from a logical point of view, teaching assistants are students.

Comment: But Logically student needn't have any properties from lecturer. Better would be to have a different interface for students. TA would implement both students and teachers interface.

Comment: That's why Lecturer is just an interface.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to have `Teacher` and `Teachable` interfaces
and then have `Lecturer` implement `Teacher` (for want of a word like Teacherable!), `Student` implement `Teachable` and `TA` implement both `Teacher` and  `Teachable`.

`Lecturer`, `Student` and `TA` could all extend `Faculty_Staff`.

Answer (score 1):

[tbodt's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305053/interfaces-in-multiple-inheritance-in-java-modelling-issue/18305061#18305061), in my opinion, is generally sound. You just have to ask: if some client code needs a `Lecturer`, would an instance of a TA suffice? If there's an issue with that, you can choose to design it with composition, abstracting the ability to teach into a separate class of its own, something like `TeachingJob` (I can't think of a better name). This way the only thing that actual `Professor`s and `TeachingAssistant`s share is that they have similar teaching jobs; they do not belong to the same "class" (interface actually).

Hybrid approach would be to involve `TeachingJob` with the `Lecturer` interface, e.g. `Lecturer` would have a `assign(TeachingJob assignment)` method.